# Filament - Can i change default authentication in filament

Tags: php, laravel-8

I wish to use filament to my new project admin dashboard.Can i change default auth table user to any other table?.A user will login using their phone number and otp.The phone number is not in user table.Also can i use apis.?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to modify [the value](https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/blob/a604ebdfff3b2486a869d3ca5fd821aae4f6504f/packages/admin/config/filament.php#L90) of `auth.pages.login` in `app/config/filament.php`. Just replace it with your class with custom login logic:

```php
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Auth
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the configuration that Filament will use to handle authentication
    | into the admin panel.
    |
    */

    'auth' => [
        'guard' => env('FILAMENT_AUTH_GUARD', 'web'),
        'pages' => [
            'login' => \Your\Custom\LoginLogic::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

In the `auth` config, create a new provider:

```
'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ],
```

Then create a new guard that uses the new provider:

```php
'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
```

Here is my updated `auth.php` config:

```php
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
    
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],

    ],
```

Now I can change the authentication guard in filament `AdminServiceProvider`:

```php
->authGuard('admin')
```

Answer (score 2):

For Filamentphp V3, there is no `auth.pages.login` config option. Instead, you can copy the `vendor/filament/filament/src/Pages/Auth/Login.php` to `app/Filament/Pages`.

To point to your new login class, go to `app/Providers/Filament/AdminPanelProvider.php` and change the `->login()` to `->login(App\Filament\Pages\Login::class)`

You can now modify class as needed including the `authenticate` method.